# How to read and display JSON responses without headers

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html

I have following JSON response.

```
{
    "2b0ce06": [
        "",
        41.56,
        -83.99,
        71,
        2900,
        177,
        "3074",
        "T-F5M",
        "SR22",
        "",
        1392140095,
        "DLH",
        "TOL",
        "",
        0,
        0,
        "SR22",
        0
    ]
}
```

I need to display this in HTML5. How could I do this?

Comment: what do you mean "withou theaders" ?

Comment: @Curt What are you talking about?

Comment: If you have that string, use it like a string. Or you could check/fix it as json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
myJSON["2b0ce06"][1] //=> 41.56
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have it as a string in a variable you will need to call 
    JSON.parse(data) 
first.